# POWER BI - DENEB - GANTT CHART - EVOLUTION

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega, deneb

I came across the following gantt graph, made in Vega.
I would like to know if we can modify the code and if so how, in order to make the following two changes:
1: add a scroll bar at the bottom to scroll only the schedule, but not the tasks?
2: How do you add milestones to the graph?

If anyone can answer, that would be great.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWmde.png)

upgrading the vega code in the gantt graph

Code is from https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json
description": "Dataviz by David Bacci: [https://www.linkedin.com/in/davbacci/"](https://www.linkedin.com/in/davbacci/%22)

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 1):

Scrollbars cannot be added to this chart.

To add a milestone, ensure your start date and end date are the same and set milestone to true like in the example provided.

```
 "milestone": true,
  "start": "13/03/2023",
  "end": "13/03/2023",
```